# Reinstall Ubuntu over version installed by my son using Windows installer

Tags: installation

My youngster installed Ubuntu using a Windows installer.   I tried uninstalling using the uninstall included in the Ubuntu directory in Windows.   That doesn't work.   Is it safe for me to instal Ubuntu from a CD over the version already there.   Is there going to be a problem with the dual boot or will the new installation overwrite the windows boot loader which the previous installation set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu in the same partition where the previous version of Ubuntu is installed. Windows boot loader will not be affected in any way.